# Angular JS Conditional Css Class not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below the code gives output **15**

```
<h1>{{model.ItemExpireAlertTime}}</h1>
```

however, when I tried to add conditional css class, it is not working for some reason.

```
<span timer interval="1000" countdown="item.ExpireTicksInSeconds">
   <span ng-class="minutes < model.ItemExpireAlertTime ? 'item-expire-alert' : '' " ng-show="minutes < 10">0</span>{{minutes}} dk 
   <span ng-show="seconds < 10">0</span>{{seconds}} sn
</span>
```

How can I add alert class when minutes is smaller than ItemExpireAlertTime ?

Comment: Why does ng-show have a conditional? sounds like something for the controller. Maybe try `ng-if`

Comment: @gerdi because there is a timer and countdown here, so if minutes are smaller than 10 min, first number will be 0 like 10:00 -> 09:59 -> 09:58

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ng-class="{'item-expire-alert': minutes < model.ItemExpireAlertTime}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have your `ng-class` the wrong way around, try this:

```
<span timer interval="1000" countdown="item.ExpireTicksInSeconds">
  <span ng-class="{'item-expire-alert': minutes < model.ItemExpireAlertTime}" ng-show="minutes < 10">0</span>{{minutes}} dk 
  <span ng-show="seconds < 10">0</span>{{seconds}} sn
</span>
```